# Content Organizer to Route Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-organizer

We have scenario where user designs a page and submit the page to system and then system identifies the correct location of the page within site collection and move the page there.

Above requirement can be easily met by using OOB SharePoint Content organizer option. But unfortunately when you create/submit a page to drop off library it throws an asp.net error. I am aware that we can't add pages to document library and that is the reason for that error.

But [TechNet site advise to use Content Organizer feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721053%28v=office.14%29.aspx) to handle large page library.

Can someone please guide me on how to use content organizer for Pages..

Comment: have you figured out solution to your question ?